# fsockopen timing out due to no new line being added to reply

Tags: php, fgets, fsockopen

The string that is returned back from server does not contain a new line. What would be a better method or replace fgets since also the string length is not known until the data is received.

At the moment im using 200 character count but this is truncating the full string. When the # is exceeded we are presented with internal server 500.

```
$fp = fsockopen("IP Address", 2000, $errno, $errstr, 20);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, 'String of Data');

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 200);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: According to [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), length is optional and _If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line._ So have you tried `echo fgets($fp);`

Comment: Getting the same result when just using echo fgets($fp); Error 500 after about a minute and 40ish seconds.

Comment: 1 Minute and 30 seconds seems to be some kind of maximum execution time limit. Do you know what is your php maximum execution time? Also 500 Internal Server Error is shown when your php code has fatal errors but error displaying is switched off. So have you tried `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see the error itself instead of 500 error page?

Comment: I was able to get a faster reply by using echo fread($fp, 90000000);